# How can I get the hour difference between dates within 24 hours with moment.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, time, momentjs

I have an object with the field of "created' with a date in which the object was created. Now I want to keep track of "How many hours ago" the object was created with **moment.js**.

My goal is to have the time display like the example below.

```
Created: 1hr ago

Created: 5hrs ago

Created: 9hrs ago

Created: 12hrs ago

Created: 14hrs ago

Created: 18hrs ago

Created: 24hrs ago
```

All the way within a 24 hour day.

So I tried this with moment:

```
    var $created = "2016-05-01T09:58:26.796Z";
    var $now = new Date();

    var $lastCreatedHour = moment( moment( moment().format('H') ).diff( moment( $created ).format('H') ) ).format('H') + " hrs ago";

console.log("Created: " + $lastCreatedHour);
```

My logic here is simple, just tried getting the difference between ***the current times hour*** and the ***$created hour***.

I actually tried many different things and none of them worked either they are a number off or they wont work within a 24 hour day and only within a 12 hour span.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/abufnuen/4/)

I'm not the best with Dates help is appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for all times to be in hours, then the answer from stdob-- is fine.

It is worth noting that Moment has `.fromNow()` built in. Simply take the date string for when your item was created, pass that to the moment constructor, and call the function:

```
moment($created).fromNow();
```

As a practical example:

```
moment("2016-05-01T09:58:26.796Z").fromNow()
"2 hours ago"
```

or, for longer ago:

```
moment("2016-04-28T09:58:26.796Z").fromNow()
"3 days ago"
```

This function will give a little more user friendly output, going from 'a few seconds ago' to 'x minutes ago' to 'y hours ago' and into days, months and years.

The output text of fromNow can be customized. See http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/ for the basic documentation and http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time/ for customization instructions.

As a final best practice note, it should never be necessary to use a javascript Date object with Moment.js unless you have a third party API that requires a date. For what you are doing though, no Date needed.

Comment: Wow Maggie this is awesome and an all around better solution for me. I think I will actually go with your answer even though it's not just the 'hour'. Thank you so much for sharing that information Maggie

Answer (score 2):

```
var $lastFeedHour = $now.diff( $created, 'hours', true)  + " hrs ago";
```

[ https://jsfiddle.net/bjdtkfLs/ ]

[ http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/ ]

Comment: Hey thank you so much for your help, this solution worked great except the 3rd parameter needs to be false. Anyways only reason I went with Maggies answer is because it is all around a better solution for someone in my situation using moment.js. But like I said your solution worked for the 'Hour'. Thank you for sharing really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to check the date as well, this may be the answer for your question. Also, I'd like to say, your function chaining was not necessary IF (as I already said) this is what you'd like to achieve.

My result would look like this:

```
var $created = moment("2016-04-30T00:58:26.796Z");
var $now = moment();
var $lastFeedHour = moment($now.diff($created)).hour();

console.log("Created: " + $lastFeedHour + " hrs ago");
```

You can also check it live [here](https://jsfiddle.net/abufnuen/5/).

Comment: This did not work correctly for my case. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

```
var $created = "2016-04-30T10:58:26.796Z";
var $now = "2016-05-01T10:58:26.696Z";
var $lastFeedHour =  moment( moment().diff( moment( $created ) ) ).format('H');

console.log("Created: " + $lastFeedHour + " hrs ago");
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abufnuen/6/)

Comment: This solution did not work if the time is over 12 hours, gives wrong hour. Thank you for sharing!